# Emulating Gingerbread

Tags: java, android, android-holo-everywhere

I am trying to emulate Gingerbread (on the emulator) in order to test if the HoloEverywhere library works, but I am suddenly confused about how exactly to do this. There are three variables I see that can be changed:

1. Change my project build target to 2.3.3
2. Change the target API in my manifest to 10
3. Change my emulator target to 2.3.3

So which of these do I need/not need to do in order to emulate Gingerbread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create/use an emulator with target 2.3.3, and set your project's `minSdkVersion` to 10 for testing. There should be no need to change the `targetSdkVersion` as the emulator already force your project to use SDK level 10 in this case.

Comment: But do I need to change my project build target to Android 2.3.3?

Comment: This should be the same case as targetSdkVersion. (i.e. you don't need to change it)

Comment: Not the targetSdkVersion - the project build target. It is accessible through project properties.

Comment: The project build target specify the compile-time API level you use to build your project in Eclipse; while the targetSdkVersion is an IDE-independent property that specify which API level your project is going to support to the furthest. Normally, they should be set to the same API level.

Answer (score 0):

Click Window>Virtual Device Manager>New  then set the resolution and ram and everything, then select the version of android you want to run in the target drop down menu, then when you run it through eclipse you can select that device with gingerbread.

More info here: http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/index.html

Hope it helps!

I think that's what you were asking, right?